# How to get a object key

Tags: javascript

Can someone help me with some code to get a key within the object so i have this

```js
var data =[ {
  "customer_name": "Marietjie",
  "customer_surname": "Short",
  "times": "12:00 to 13:00",
  "order_id": "241918",
  "vendor": [
    "Pick n Pay",
    "Woolworths"
  ],
  "customer_phone": "0609880707",
  "smart_shopper": "",
  "dischem_reward": "",
  "woolworths_reward": ""
}]
var name = data.customer_name;
console.log(name);
```

and i want to get the value of customer name, i tried this `var name = data.customer_name` but i got `undefined` can some help me with the code

Comment: `data.customer_name` should work.

Comment: Cant reproduce.

Comment: Your code works as expected.

Comment: it works even in the OP's example :D

Comment: Where does the data come from? Are you getting the data asynchronously, e.g. via AJAX? This smells like you trying to access data before it is available.

Answer (score 0):

Your object is in an array.

You cannot just ignore the array.

```
var object = data[0];
var name = object.customer_name
```